# Adding custom serializer to different parts of a redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, json-deserialization, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

Suppose I created a [slice](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux#using-createslice) which is used to manage pets, and it uses `Date` as one of the properties of the pet.

Given that redux by itself is [not able](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state) to serialize `Date`, I would like to have a solution which allows me to supply a custom serializer/de-serializer for `Date`.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "custom serializer/deserializer" for a Redux store by itself. The Redux state contains exactly what your slice reducers return, with no other transformations.

We normally recommend that you keep date values in state as either ISO strings or numeric timestamps, and convert back to dates in components if actually needed.

Comment: That was my mistake. I use redux-persist, which I now believe is what serializes the store to local storage. I will look to see if there is a way to create custom serializers for redux-persist

Comment: Yep, that makes sense.  FWIW, one of the reasons we recommend keeping all state serializable is to avoid problems with this exact use case - persistence.

Comment: This is what I ended up going with. Turns out I didn't really need that particular state to be persisted, so I just blacklisted the reducer from redux-persist. In the future, I may come back to this to remind myself to look for a different way of persisting class types